# draw something using PaintEventArgs in timer

Tags: c#

Okay, what I'm trying to do is to draw circles for example in some random places on the form using a timer that draw each 5 second for example,

```
    private void drawSomething(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd_X = new Random();
        Random rnd_Y = new Random();
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, Convert.ToInt16(rnd_X.Next(250, 500)), Convert.ToInt16(rnd_Y.Next(250, 500)),50,50);
    }
```

but i got error because i have to use the function that automaticlly added by clicking on the timer.

this :

```
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

i also tried to change the timer properties on the designer like this :

```
        // timer2
        // 
        this.timer2.Enabled = true;
        this.timer2.Interval = 500;
        this.timer2.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.drawSomething);
```

**Error: No overload for 'wew' matches delegate 'EventHandler'

Comment: What is `wew` ?

Comment: In the `drawSomething` method do a `Refresh` to the form given you're drawing randomly, otherwise you could use `Invalidate`.

Comment: Before coding you need to __decide__: Shall the drawings be __persistent__ or be __volatile__? Persistent drawing __needs__ to be triggered from the `Paint` event using its `e.Graphics` object. Your `Tick` could add andother set of data to a list and then trigger the `Paint` event to draw them __all__ by `Invalidating` the drawing surface. For __non-persistent__ drawing you can use `CreateGraphics` to create a volatile `Graphics` object in your `Tick` and draw with it. The drawing will soon disappear though..

Comment: sorry, instead of wew -> drawSomething

Comment: i can ask it more simple, what i need to do is to run the function drawSomething each 5 seconds

Comment: _i can ask it more simple_ First answer the basic question: Persistent or non-persistent ?!

Comment: i want it to be non-persistent

Comment: Then create a fresh Graphics object  (with CreateGraphics) in theTick event and use it for drawing..! No need to pass anything in..

Comment: maybe what you are saying is higher than my level, i dont understand

Comment: do you mean something like this ? 
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            PaintEventArgs draw=...;

            Random rnd_X = new Random();

            Random rnd_Y = new Random();
            draw.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, Convert.ToInt16(rnd_X.Next(250, 500)), Convert.ToInt16(rnd_Y.Next(250, 500)), 50, 50);
        }